# Adding a Shadow to a NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a `NSImageView` and want to add a shadow. I've tried doing it programmatically with:

```
NSShadow *shadow = [[[NSShadow alloc] init] autorelease];
[shadow setShadowBlurRadius:4.0f];
[shadow setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(4.0f, 4.0f)];
[shadow setShadowColor:[NSColor blackColor]];

[view setShadow:shadow];
```

But it won't appear. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You could try creating an empty NSImage (of the same size as the one you want to draw), `lockFocus` on it, set the shadow, and draw the original into the new one (and `unlockFocus`).  I use that technique for tinting images; can't guarantee it'll work for shadow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set the parameters of the shadow. By default, it's all zeroes, so it has no visible effect on a view.

See `-setShadowColor:`, `-setShadowRadius:`, and `-setShadowOffset:` on `NSShadow`, I believe.

Comment: I tried adding all the above to no effect. I updated the above sample.

Comment: Is your view also backed by a `CALayer`? If not, you must enable Core Animation backing by sending `setWantsLayer:` (with a value of `YES`) to your view before setting the shadow.

Comment: @Jonathan: that was what I was about to post as an answer indeed. `setShadow:` simply copies the shadow's properties to the Core Animation layer, so the view must be backed by a `CALayer`. This is also noticeable when you want to apply a shadow to a view using Interface Builder.

Comment: Ayup. Have had my head in iOS for a while, so it briefly slipped my mind that on the Mac, views are not layer-backed by default. :)

Comment: Any way to avoid clipping the shadow if once a CALayer is enabled?

Comment: I believe if the superview is also layer-backed, the clipping rules change, but it has been a while.

Comment: Not to sound crass, but to award a bounty, you must actively click the appropriate button in your UI. (Okay, that sounded crass anyway, didn't it?)

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry! I tried to add it when I marked an answer but it required waiting a day (and then I forgot). My apologies!

Comment: No worries. I just didn't want that precious precious rep to go to waste. Precious, delicious rep...

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4

```
let shadow = NSShadow()
shadow.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(2, -2)
shadow.shadowColor = NSColor.lightGray
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 3

imageView.wantsLayer = true
imageView.shadow = shadow
```