# Objective C - OS X - Issue adding NSShadow to NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimageview, nsshadow

I am trying to add a shadow to a NSImageView on an MAC application.

I created a custom NSImageView class "ShadowView.h" and modified the drawRect: like so:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius:5];
    [shadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(30.0, 3.0)];
    [shadow setShadowColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    [shadow set];

    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    [self setShadow:shadow];
}
```

However nothing happens. Also, when I debug I can see the above code being called. I looked at this question from 5 years ago but it seems to not work anymore

[Adding a Shadow to a NSImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704047/adding-a-shadow-to-a-nsimageview)

Thank you!

Comment: Does your view's superview also have layer-backing enabled? I built a quick test app with this code, and unless the superview _also_ has layer backing, the shadow gets clipped at the edge of the view bounds. Perhaps there is a shadow, but it's outside your image view, and the superview doesn't have a layer?

Comment: Also, and this might be a stupid question, do you have an image in the image view? The shadow for an `NSImageView` is calculated based on the image's alpha, so if there's no image, there's no shadow.

Comment: @Arclite The issue was that my superview did not have layer-backing enabled! I just added [self.view wantsLayer:YES] to my viewController viewDidLoad. If you make it an answer I can accept it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: Done! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a shadow to a view, that view's superview *also* needs to have layer-backing enabled. If it doesn't, the view's shadow gets clipped at its own bounds, as seen in this sample app:

[image: clipped shadow]

Make sure you call `-setWantsLayer:YES` on your view's superview (or check the "Core Animation Layer" checkbox in Interface Builder) in order to make sure the shadow is completely visible:

[image: full shadow]

Answer (score 0):

You should set these somewhere else like, initWithFrame: take them out of the drawRect:

```
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
[self setShadow:shadow];
```